# Support for always encrypted with transaction replication in SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

I would like to use  Always Encrypted as part of SQL 2017 or SQL 2019 to encrypt a few columns but those columns are currently involved in transactional replication in the architecture.  Always Encrypted does not appear to support transactional replication in SQL 2017 (would like to confirm) and I cannot find an authoritative answer for support with SQL 2019.

We successfully tested implementing Always Encrypted in SQL 2017 on columns in a table that are not involved in transactional replication.  We could not get Always Encrypted to work for tables for those columns involved in replication.  This validates the documentation that it is not supported. Not sure if there are any workarounds. The documentation for  SQL 2019 seems to mirror the SQL 2017 documentation but I want to validate the limitation because I don't know if the documentation has been updated for the soon-to-be-released version of SQL Server.

Not code related

I was hoping that a key technology in SQL Server (transactional replication) would have introduced support for Always Encrypted columns over the course of 3 releases.